Is there a way to use workday app with SSO if I have 4 different M365 tenants?
We are setting up a SSO connection to Workday, trying to use 4 different enterprise applications. Those 4 applications are supposed to reach 4 tenants inside workday, but they are all rerouting to the same one. The enterprise applications have been set up using the documentation listed below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/saas-apps/workday-tutorial
When I try to login with the other 3 tenants is showing me this error message: Request Error
Your browser is requesting a page or a resource from the wittobriens3 tenant, but you're currently signed into the wittobriens1 tenant. Please clear your browser cache and sign into your desired Workday tenant again.
I don't know what else I can do.
